# How to make divs inline (inline-block not working) for slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a slider from div to div but the position of the div is always wrong I don't seem to manage to code it right to fix it in the right position, I have tried floats, inline everything but nothing seems to work. so the parent class is "products" the ensemble class is "product" and each div is "product-1, product-2 etc."

Here is the whole wesite from a to z.

````
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Paritrāṇa Sari collection</title>

    <script
  src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <!--  <script src="function.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*:root {
    cursor: url(model.png), auto;
}*/
/*html {zoom: 160%;}*/
body {
   background-color: #e4e0dd;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
#c {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
}
#info {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    top: -1px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 420px;
    height: auto;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
#top {
    /*background: #fff;*/
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  /*  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;*/
}
p {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0px 16px;
}


.center {
  text-align: center;
}
#net {
  text-align:center;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size:19px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding:8px 12px;
  border-radius:8px;
  display:block;
  color:#888;
}



.bull {
  opacity: 0.3;
  margin: 0 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.column {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 5px;

}
.row_1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column_1 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    flex: 1;
  }
   .column_1 {
    flex: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  ._25 {
    flex: 1.5;
  }
  ._55 {
    flex: 7.5;
  }
  ._20 {
    flex: 2;
  }
}
 a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

 a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
background: black;}

 a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
background: black;
}
img {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  object-position: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
width: 50%;
height: auto;
z-index: 1000;
 
}

.signupsubmit {
    transform: rotateY(50deg) rotateX(50deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(50deg) rotateX(50deg);
    transition: 1s;
                }
        .signupsubmit:hover {   
-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);
}
/*.active {
    zoom: 160%;
}*/
body .cursor {
  pointer-events: none;
}
body .cursor__ball {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  z-index: 1000;
}
body .cursor__ball circle {
  fill: #f7f8fa;
}

section {float: left;}
::selection {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    color: white;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    color: white;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

a :hover {
    z-index: 10000000;
}

.hidden {
    /* display: none; */
    opacity: 0;
}

/* */

.container {
   position: absolute;
 /*   top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
 /* width: 200vh;
    height: 100vh;*/
  /*  background-color: aqua;*/

   */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.products {
    position: relative;
     display: inline-block; 
  /* width: 1000%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0%;
   /* background-color: blueviolet;*/*/
    transition: left .5s ease-in-out;
}

.product {
   /* width: 70vh;
    height: 100%;*/
    float: left;
    display: inline-block; 
}

.product-1 {
  /*  background-color: beige;*/
}
.product-2 {
    background-color: red;
}
.product-3 {
    background-color: slategray;
}
.product-4 {
    background-color: burlywood;
}

.buttonLeft, .buttonRight {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    top: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}

.buttonLeft:hover, .buttonRight:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.buttonLeft {
    left: 0px;
    cursor: w-resize;
}

.buttonRight {
    right: 0px;
    cursor: e-resize;

}
 </style>
 <script>
function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
  var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  /*create lens:*/
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  /*insert lens:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
  result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
  /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;}
    if (x < 0) {x = 0;}
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;}
    if (y < 0) {y = 0;}
    /*set the position of the lens:*/
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /*display what the lens "sees":*/
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <!-- cursor -->
  <div class="cursor">
    <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--big">
      <svg height="60" width="60">
        <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="16" stroke-width="0"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- small ball cursor -->
    <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--small">
      <svg height="10" width="10">
        <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- cursor end -->
  <!-- navigation -->
  <nav>
    <div class="row" style="background-color:white;">
      <div class="column">
        <a href="">Paritrāṇa Sari collection</a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href=""> Concept</a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href=""> Process</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color:white;">
      <div class="column">
        <a href=""> Red sari N°1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href=""> Orange sari N°2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href=""> Saffron sari N°3</a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href=""> Yellow sari N°4</a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href=""> Turmeric sari N°5</a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href=""> Green sari N°6</a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href=""> Blue sari N°7</a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href=""> Pink sari N°8</a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href=""> Black sari N°9</a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href=""> White sariN°10</a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href=""> Violet sari N°11</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- navigation end -->

  <!-- wrapper slider -->
  <section class="container">
  <div class="products">
  <div class="wrapper product product-1">
    <img src="./img.png" style="margin-top: -2000px; position: absolute;" />
    <canvas
      width="1900"
      height="300"
      style="margin-top: -2000px; position: absolute;"
    ></canvas>

    <div class="row_1">
      <!-- <div style="overflow:auto"> -->
      <div class="column _25" style="overflow-y: auto;">
        Project photoshoot
        <div id="img1" class="signupsubmit" style="width:100%;">
          <img src="model.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="img1" class="signupsubmit" style="width:100%;">
          <img src="model.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="img1" class="signupsubmit" style="width:100%;">
          <img src="model.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="signupsubmit" style="width:100%;">
          <img src="model.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="signupsubmit" style="width:100%;">
          <img src="model.png" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column _55">
        <canvas id="c" width="800" height="376"> </canvas>

        <div class="row_1">
          <div class="column_1">
            <div id="top">
              <a id="close" href="">Reset tissue —</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column_1">
            <div>
             <p>This project is based on the red celebratory color………</p>
             
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column_1">
            <div style="background-color:red;height: 50px;width: 50px;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="column _20 signupsubmit"
          style="border-top: 1px solid black;border-right: 0px;"
        >
          Red is a celebratory color. It commemorates a couple’s union. It
          symbolizes love, sensuality, and passion. That’s why it features
          prominently in auspicious occasions, such as weddings, festivals, and
          births. As red also signifies chastity, it is the color of choice for
          brides. After the wedding ceremony, the bride adopts a red spot on the
          forehead called “bindi,” which cements her marital status. When she
          dies, her family wraps her in red fabric for cremation. As red also
          depicts dominance, it empowers the saree wearer and draws attention
          toward her. It’s no surprise that extroverts and A-type personalities
          prefer red. Pairing a red saree with a gold top amplifies the look. To
          tone it down, use a silver blouse instead. Accessorize with silver or
          gold jewelry. Red is associated with Durga, a Hindu goddess with a red
          tongue, red eyes, and a blazing image. That’s why devotees use it
          extensively in prayer rituals. Worshippers throw red powder on
          deities’ statues during prayer ceremonies and phallic symbols because
          red is the color of Kshatriya, the warrior caste. Designers dress
          charitable, brave, and protective deities in red. Red also symbolizes
          fertility and prosperity because it is the color of the clay that
          produces spices and harvests, which in turn, improve lives.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="wrapper product product-2" style="float: left;display: inline;clear: both;top: 0;position: absolute;">
    <img src="./img2.png" style="margin-top: -2000px; position: absolute;" />
    <canvas
      width="1900"
      height="300"
      style="margin-top: -2000px; position: absolute;"
    ></canvas>

    <div class="row_1">
      <!-- <div style="overflow:auto"> -->
      <div class="column _25" style="overflow-y: auto;">
        Project photoshoot
        <div id="img1" class="signupsubmit" style="width:100%;">
          <img src="model.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="img1" class="signupsubmit" style="width:100%;">
          <img src="model.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="img1" class="signupsubmit" style="width:100%;">
          <img src="model.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="signupsubmit" style="width:100%;">
          <img src="model.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="signupsubmit" style="width:100%;">
          <img src="model.png" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column _55">
        <canvas id="c" width="800" height="376"> </canvas>

        <div class="row_1">
          <div class="column_1">
            <div id="top">
              <a id="close" href="">Reset tissue —</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column_1">
            <div>
             <p>This project is based on the red celebratory color………</p>
             
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column_1">
            <div style="background-color:red;height: 50px;width: 50px;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="column _20 signupsubmit"
          style="border-top: 1px solid black;border-right: 0px;"
        >
          Orange attracts attention and energy like the color red, except it’s more sedate. It signifies freshness and brightness. Not all skin tones can carry this color, but for those whose complexions can pull it off in their clothing, it helps put them in a sunny disposition.
According to CNN’s Colorscope report, a series exploring color perception across cultures,  many Eastern religions consider orange a sacred color. In Hinduism, orange represents fire and virtuosity. That’s why their monks wear orange robes. Buddhist ones too.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hidden buttonLeft"></div>
            <div class="hidden buttonRight"></div>
</section>
    <!-- wrapper slider end -->

    <!-- footer -->
    <footer
      style="position: fixed;bottom: 0;width: 100%;background-color: white;border-top:1px solid black;"
    >
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">©Copyright Angelo Barbattini</div>
        <div class="column">ECAL 2022</div>
      </div>
    </footer>
<!-- footer end -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {

    
}

var offsetProducts = 0;
var numberProducts = 2; //nombre de project -1, car on commence à compter à partir de 0

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");


    // $(".buttonLeft").on("click", function() {
    //     console.log(offsetProducts);
    //     if (offsetProducts > numberProducts * -100) offsetProducts = offsetProducts - 100;
    //     $(".products").css("left", offsetProducts + "%");
    // });

    // $(".buttonRight").on("click", function() {
    //     console.log("right Click");
    //     if (offsetProducts < 0) offsetProducts = offsetProducts + 100;
    //     $(".products").css("left", offsetProducts + "%");
    // });

    $(".buttonLeft").on("click", function() {
        console.log(offsetProducts);
        if (offsetProducts < 0) offsetProducts = offsetProducts + 100;
        $(".products").css("left", offsetProducts + "%");
    });

    $(".buttonRight").on("click", function() {
        console.log("right Click");
        if (offsetProducts > numberProducts * -100) offsetProducts = offsetProducts - 100;
        $(".products").css("left", offsetProducts + "%");
    });
    
});




</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    const mycanvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    const mycontext = mycanvas.getContext('2d');

    // settings


    var physics_accuracy = 20,
      mouse_influence = 10,
      mouse_cut = 6,
      gravity = 1200,
      cloth_height = 40,
      cloth_width = 120,
      start_y = 10,
      spacing = 7,
      tear_distance = 60;


    window.requestAnimFrame =
      window.requestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };

    var canvas,
      ctx,
      cloth,
      boundsx,
      boundsy,
      mouse = {
        down: false,
        button: 1,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        px: 0,
        py: 0
      };

    window.onload = function() {
      // ADDED TO BRING IN THE IMAGE
      mycontext.clearRect(0, 0, mycanvas.width, mycanvas.height);
      mycontext.drawImage(document.querySelector('img'), 0, 0, 1180, 376);


      canvas = document.getElementById('c');
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
      canvas.height = 376;

      canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
        mouse.button = e.which;
        mouse.px = mouse.x;
        mouse.py = mouse.y;
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouse.x = e.clientX - rect.left,
          mouse.y = e.clientY - rect.top,
          mouse.down = true;
        e.preventDefault();
      };

      canvas.onmouseup = function(e) {
        mouse.down = false;
        e.preventDefault();
      };

      canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
        mouse.px = mouse.x;
        mouse.py = mouse.y;
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouse.x = e.clientX - rect.left,
          mouse.y = e.clientY - rect.top,
          e.preventDefault();
      };

      canvas.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      };

      boundsx = canvas.width - 1;
      boundsy = canvas.height - 1;

      ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(222,222,222,0.6)';
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'magenta';
      cloth = new Cloth();
      update();
    };

    var Point = function(x, y) {

      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.px = x;
      this.py = y;
      this.vx = 0;
      this.vy = 0;
      this.pin_x = null;
      this.pin_y = null;
      this.constraints = [];
      //added - remember where this point was originally so we can get the right bit of the img
      this.origx = x;
      this.origy = y;
    };

    Point.prototype.update = function(delta) {

      if (mouse.down) {

        var diff_x = this.x - mouse.x,
          diff_y = this.y - mouse.y,
          dist = Math.sqrt(diff_x * diff_x + diff_y * diff_y);

        if (mouse.button == 1) {

          if (dist < mouse_influence) {
            this.px = this.x - (mouse.x - mouse.px) * 1.8;
            this.py = this.y - (mouse.y - mouse.py) * 1.8;
          }

        } else if (dist < mouse_cut) this.constraints = [];
      }

      this.add_force(0, gravity);

      delta *= delta;
      nx = this.x + ((this.x - this.px) * .99) + ((this.vx / 2) * delta);
      ny = this.y + ((this.y - this.py) * .99) + ((this.vy / 2) * delta);

      this.px = this.x;
      this.py = this.y;

      this.x = nx;
      this.y = ny;

      this.vy = this.vx = 0
    };

    Point.prototype.draw = function() {

      if (this.constraints.length <= 0) return;

      var i = this.constraints.length;
      while (i--) this.constraints[i].draw();
    };

    Point.prototype.resolve_constraints = function() {

      if (this.pin_x != null && this.pin_y != null) {

        this.x = this.pin_x;
        this.y = this.pin_y;
        return;
      }

      var i = this.constraints.length;
      while (i--) this.constraints[i].resolve();

      this.x > boundsx ? this.x = 2 * boundsx - this.x : 1 > this.x && (this.x = 2 - this.x);
      this.y < 1 ? this.y = 2 - this.y : this.y > boundsy && (this.y = 2 * boundsy - this.y);
    };

    Point.prototype.attach = function(point) {

      this.constraints.push(
        new Constraint(this, point)
      );
    };

    Point.prototype.remove_constraint = function(lnk) {

      var i = this.constraints.length;
      while (i--)
        if (this.constraints[i] == lnk) this.constraints.splice(i, 1);
    };

    Point.prototype.add_force = function(x, y) {

      this.vx += x;
      this.vy += y;
    };

    Point.prototype.pin = function(pinx, piny) {
      this.pin_x = pinx;
      this.pin_y = piny;
    };

    var Constraint = function(p1, p2) {

      this.p1 = p1;
      this.p2 = p2;
      this.length = spacing;
    };

    Constraint.prototype.resolve = function() {

      var diff_x = this.p1.x - this.p2.x,
        diff_y = this.p1.y - this.p2.y,
        dist = Math.sqrt(diff_x * diff_x + diff_y * diff_y),
        diff = (this.length - dist) / dist;

      if (dist > tear_distance) this.p1.remove_constraint(this);

      var px = diff_x * diff * 0.7;
      var py = diff_y * diff * 0.5;

      this.p1.x += px;
      this.p1.y += py;
      this.p2.x -= px;
      this.p2.y -= py;
    };
    let num = 0;
    Constraint.prototype.draw = function() {

      ctx.drawImage(mycanvas, this.p1.origx, this.p1.origy, spacing, spacing, this.p1.x, this.p1.y, spacing + 1, spacing + 1);
    };

    var Cloth = function() {

      this.points = [];

      var start_x = canvas.width / 2 - cloth_width * spacing / 2;
      // alert(start_x);

      for (var y = 0; y <= cloth_height; y++) {

        for (var x = 0; x <= cloth_width; x++) {

          var p = new Point(start_x + x * spacing, start_y + y * spacing);

          x != 0 && p.attach(this.points[this.points.length - 1]);
          y == 0 && p.pin(p.x, p.y);
          y != 0 && p.attach(this.points[x + (y - 1) * (cloth_width + 1)])

          this.points.push(p);
        }
      }
    };

    Cloth.prototype.update = function() {

      var i = physics_accuracy;

      while (i--) {
        var p = this.points.length;
        while (p--) this.points[p].resolve_constraints();
      }

      i = this.points.length;
      while (i--) this.points[i].update(.016);
    };

    Cloth.prototype.draw = function() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.beginPath();

      var i = cloth.points.length;
      while (i--) cloth.points[i].draw();

      ctx.stroke();
    };

    function update() {

      cloth.update();
      cloth.draw();

      requestAnimFrame(update);
    }
  </script>
  <script>
imageZoom("myimage", "myresult");
</script>
<!--  <script type="text/javascript"> document.body.onclick = function () {document.body.style.zoom="150%"}</script> 
 -->  <script type="text/javascript"> $('#myButton').click(function() { document.body.style.zoom="160%" });</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">$(function(){
    $('h3').click(function(){
        $('h3.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});</script>
<script type="text/javascript">const $bigBall = document.querySelector(".cursor__ball--big");
const $smallBall = document.querySelector(".cursor__ball--small");
const $hoverables = document.querySelectorAll(".hoverable");

// Listeners
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
for (let i = 0; i < $hoverables.length; i++) {
  $hoverables[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", onMouseHover);
  $hoverables[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", onMouseHoverOut);
}

// Move the cursor
function onMouseMove(e) {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, 0.4, {
    x: e.pageX - 15,
    y: e.pageY - 15
  });
  TweenMax.to($smallBall, 0.1, {
    x: e.pageX - 5,
    y: e.pageY - 7
  });
}

// Hover an element
function onMouseHover() {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, 0.3, {
    scale: 4
  });
}
function onMouseHoverOut() {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, 0.3, {
    scale: 1
  });
}</script>
  <script>
      // Get the img object using its Id
      img = document.getElementById("img1");
      // Function to increase image size
      function enlargeImg() {
        // Set image size to 1.5 times original
        img.style.transform = "scale(1.5)";
        // Animation effect 
        img.style.transition = "transform 0.25s ease";
      }
      // Function to reset image size
      function resetImg() {
        // Set image size to original
        img.style.transform = "scale(1)";
        img.style.transition = "transform 0.25s ease";
      }
    </script>
</script>

</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Please read [mcve].  The idea is to provide *just enough* code to demonstrate your issue, not just dump your entire site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the div style to display flex like this:

```
div {
display: flex;
flex: 1
///
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it completely moved all my divs around, but i think the problem is in the js somewhere.